# Install windows Updates(msu files) into running system Windows Vista 7, 8 ,8.1

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update

my PDC is Windows2008 R2 standart and I need to install this emergency update in my workstations - Windows Vista 7, 8 ,8.1 with x86 and x64. 
For each version a different file.
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS15-078
What is fast and better method? via GPO? Script batch? Does Windows 8 and 8.1 aplies?
Edit: unfortunately WSUS is disabled due to lack of resources and disk space.

Comment: Where is your WSUS server?